# Why is CodeWars raising a reduce error when I can't find values in my code that do?

Tags: python

So I have to write code for the following [CodeWars Kata](https://www.codewars.com/kata/54d7660d2daf68c619000d95/train/python) and for some reason, my code won't work. I tried testing a bunch of other dummy values but nothing raises the error when I run it, and I can't see what values they're testing. Any help?

```py
from functools import reduce
def gcd(a,b):
    if b == 0:
        return a
    else:
        return gcd(b, a%b)

def lcm(a,b): #euclid
    return (a*b)//gcd(a,b)

def convertFracts(lst): #lcm can be computed by iteratively computing the lcm of the current value and the next element of the list
    lcd = reduce(lcm, [elem[1] for elem in lst]) #least common denom
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        lst[i][0] = lst[i][0]*(lcd//lst[i][1]) #numerator, ex. 1/2 = 1*(12/2) / 12
        lst[i][1] = lcd
    return lst
    
a = [[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4]]
print(convertFracts(a))
```

The error log on their end:

```
Passed: 1 Failed: 0 Exit Code: 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 8, in <module>
    test.assert_equals(convertFracts(a), b)
  File "/home/codewarrior/solution.py", line 12, in convertFracts
    lcd = reduce(lcm, [elem[1] for elem in lst]) #least common denom
TypeError: reduce() of empty sequence with no initial value
```

Comment: Try it with `a = []` or `a = [[]]` and see for yourself.

Comment: Ohhh I see thanks, I thought we had to assume all the input values were 2D arrays. Thanks a lot!